# Pandas API on Spark crashes after pandas transforms. How do I fix it?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

```
import pyspark.pandas as ppd
pdf = ppd.read_csv("somefile.csv", header=0, sep=",")

#(It can't be memory, I've limited my sample to nrec=10)

def makeStringLonger(inputString)
   return inputString + "random more stuff" + inputString

pdf["someColumn"] = pdf["someColumn"].transform(makeStringLonger)

#error happens during the collection for one of these:
print(pdf)  #or sdf = pdf.to_spark()  or pdf.to_table('sometable')
```

Error:

23/03/07 17:25:21 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 5)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:599)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:581)
at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:107)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:512)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:364)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:397)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:88)
... 22 more
23/03/07 17:25:21 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 5) (localhost executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:599)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:581)
at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:107)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:512)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:364)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:397)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:88)
... 22 more

23/03/07 17:25:21 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 7.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
File Redacted
res = df.to_spark().take(9)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 868, in take
return self.limit(num).collect()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 817, in collect
sock_info = self._jdf.collectToPython()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1321, in **call**
return_value = get_return_value(
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 190, in deco
return f(*a, **kw)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o352.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 5) (localhost executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:599)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:581)
at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:107)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:512)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:364)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:397)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:88)
... 22 more

Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:952)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2228)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2249)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2268)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:506)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:459)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.$anonfun$executeCollect$1(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:345)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.withFinalPlanUpdate(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:373)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.executeCollect(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:345)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectToPython$1(Dataset.scala:3688)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:3858)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:510)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3856)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3856)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3685)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:599)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:581)
at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:107)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:512)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:364)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:397)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:88)
... 22 more

I am at a loss to understand what's going on and how to fix it.
pandas 1.4.4
pyarrow 8.0.0
pyspark 3.3.1

What am I missing?

Comment: I suspect that it is the fact that my conversion functions library is re-loading, which is probably moving all of the function pointers on it, making a mess of things.  I have made a tweak to stop it, but I'm not sure why it was reloading the library at all.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it caused by the wrong type in the data file, it can't convert int to string (java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt),

Comment: You would think.  But I've stopped trying to do my data conversions.  My function is currently merely trying to convert from a string of a date to an ISO date string.  I stopped trying to convert it to a datetime.

Answer (score 0):

So my example setup was incomplete compared to my real code.
The conversion functions are in a custom library.  When the worker threads spool up, they were triggering my library to re-load.  This reload caused the function to be re-declared which broke the spark user defined function bindings.

The fix was to make my library detect that it was being needlessly reloaded and to silently exit that load and preserve the old load.